# Lyapunov function and stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suposse we have $f:\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$, $f(0)=0$, the system $z'=f(z)$. Let $z=(x,y)$ and $V$ a strict Lyapunov function, $V:U\longrightarrow R$, $U$ open, $V(0,0)=0$, $V(x,y)>0 \;\forall\;(x,y)\neq(0,0)$  with $\langle\nabla V(z),f(z)\rangle=-(x^2+y^2+cxy)$, with $c$ such that $x^2+y^2+cxy>0 \quad\forall\;(x,y)\neq(0,0)$. I know that the linear system $z'=Df(0,0)z$ does not need to have $(0,0)$ as an asymptotically stable point in general, but in this case?

I can not find a counterexample, but I don't believe it is true.

Comment: Are there any other conditions on coefficient $c$ ?

Comment: @Evgeny No, just $c\in\mathbb{R} \;\mid\; x^2+y^2+cxy$ is positive defined. I have tried with $c=0$ and $c=2$ as posibles values.

Comment: $c=2$ is not positive definite, only positive semidefinite, since in that case the form is $(x+y)^2$, so it is $0$ on the line $x+y=0$.

Comment: What are the conditions on $V$, something like locally negative definite?

Comment: @LukasGeyer I am sorry. I forgot to write it

Comment: One of the inequalities should go the other way. If the Lyapunov function has a minimum at $0$ and is increasing along orbits (as you have it right now), the fixed point will be unstable.

Comment: @LukasGeyer Yes, I forgot the minus

Comment: I assume that $U$ should contain $0$ as well, right?

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumptions the equilibrium point $(0,0)$ is locally asymptotically stable, which is a standard result in dynamical systems, and (without proof) stated on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_function). You can find the proof in many textbooks, but it is not hard to prove, using the fact that for solutions in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$, you have $\frac{d}{dt} V(z(t)) \le 0$ (showing local stability), and that on any compact subset of $U \setminus \{0\}$ you have a strict uniform estimate of the form $\frac{d}{dt} V(z(t)) \le -\epsilon < 0$ (showing local asymptotic stability).